# Example where adding "S"-suffix to a word yields a different, distinct word

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an example of a word where appending an "s" to it results in another dictionary word that has a meaning distinct from just the plural of the original noun?

To give an example, the dictionary entry for the "s"-suffixed word would read something like this:

> #### Foos
>
> 1. A large object
> 2. Plural of "foo"

That is, the dictionary entry contains two usages or distinct identities: one as the plural of another word, the other as a distinct dictionary word.

Comment: What is the real-world problem you are attempting to solve here?

Comment: @tchrist I am programmatically filtering a list of thousands of words that includes plurals, and don't want plurals in my final list. As an easy heuristic, I assumed that if we have any word X, and then the word Xs, the latter is the plural of X and can be discarded. I am certain that this assumption is false, though, but I am struggling to find an example at the moment, and want a concrete counter-example to this assumption.

Comment: [**stagger**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagger) (intransitive verb) *to reel from side to side*. Add an **s** to get **staggers** (*noun* - plural in form but singular or plural in construction) - *an abnormal condition of domestic animals associated with damage to the central nervous system*. But the noun obviously derives from the verb. That's not the case with **lee** (shelter) and **lees** (waste dead brewing yeast). But there must be *hundreds* of examples like that, and there's no "rule" to generate that list.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for resources. Specifically, OP wants a list of words ending in "s" that are *not* simple morphological inflexions of the same word *without* that "s" (plural, second person singular verb, etc.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's so broad-ranging in scope that it's essentially asking for trivia. A better fit on Puzzling.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is no end of these.

1. *Len* is short for *Leonard*, but *lens* means something else.
2. *Mrs* is not the plural of *Mr*.
3. A *hi* is a greeting, but *his* is a possessive pronoun.
4. A *mew* is a gull, but a *mews* is where you keep your falcons, an unrelated word.
5. A *mop* is for swabbing the deck, but a *mops* is a pug-dog.
6. *Physics* is not the plural of *physic*.
7. *Bitters* is not the plural of *bitter*.
8. A *chap* is a guy, but *chaps* are a garment.
9. *Corp* is short for corporal, but *corps* means something else.
10. *Craps* is a game, not more than one *crap*.
11. A *flinder* is a moth or butterfly, but *flinders* are fragments.
12. *Gen* is a generation as in *gen X*, but a *gens* is a Roman family or clan.
13. The plural of *die* is *dice*, not *dies* which is an unrelated singular verb.
14. *Gony* means a simpleton or a gooney, but *gonys* is not its plural but rather the keel of bird’s bill.
15. *Mos* means new wine or must, but *moss* is not its plural.
16. *As* means a Roman copper coin, but *ass* is not its plural.
17. *Specie* means coinage, but *species* is not its plural.
18. *I* is singular, but *is* is not its plural; *we* is its plural.
19. *Anyways* is not the plural of *anyway*, nor *towards* of *toward*.
20. Nearly any verb can have an *-s* added to its base form to make the present tense third person singular, not plural.